# VBA/Excel: Get cell from different sheet

Tags: excel, vba, find, cell

Long story short: I have two sheets in Excel: Sheet1 which has two cells (A1 & A2) and Sheet2 (providing some data) which looks like this:

```
  | A | B  |
--|---|----|
1 | a | 5  |
2 | b | 10 |
3 | c | 15 |
4 | ...
```

So here's my problem: in Sheet1 when I enter "b" in A1 it should automatically enter 10 in A2.

Kinda like a simple find operation which will return the cell (or column) number and use that to return the value for the cell right next to it. But how do I do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before, a VLOOKUP is the simplest and fastest way but I assume you do not want to have a formula in that cell or on that whole Sheet1 for that matter? Here is one simple way to do the same in VBA while still using a VLOOKUP - just not on Sheet1:

Use Sheet2!Z1 for calculation, if that cell is used in your workbook, just use any other unused cell in an area that is hidded for example.
Formula in Sheet2!Z1 :

```
=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!$A$1,Sheet2!$A$B,2,FALSE)
```

Simple VBA to populate Sheet1!A2:

```
sum DoIt
  Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("Z1").Value
  end sub
```

You can call the DoIt sub with a button for example and it will keep your Sheet1 / cell A2 clean of formulas.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I'm looking for (just noticed I mixed up the row numbers in my question, fixed that now).